# network usage on chromedp

Tags: go, chromedp

I am trying to find response size for every request from chromedp
I tried following code

```
chromedp.ListenTarget(
    ctx,
    func(ev interface{}){
        if ev, ok := ev.(*network.EventResponseReceived); ok {
            fmt.Println("event received:")
            fmt.Println(ev.Type)
            var len = ev.Response.EncodedDataLength;
            fmt.Println(ev.Response.URL + ":" + fmt.Sprintf("%f", len))
            return

        }
    },
)
```

But EncodedDataLength is Total number of bytes received for this request so far (As per documentation). Is there any way to get full response size.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EventLoadingFinished`.

> Network.loadingFinished #.
> Fired when HTTP request has finished loading.
> as [here](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#event-loadingFinished)

`EventLoadingFinished.EncodedDataLength` will give you the full size as this event will be triggered only once the entire response is loaded. You can use both the events and use the `RequestID` field to map them to a particular resource url.